# Can I work on a project on Github that was originally uploaded on mac on windows?

Tags: git, macos, github, window

I want to be able to work on a current and future projects on both systems. I rememeber I tried this back in an internship and there were lots of errors when working on a team with those who had a mac and windows. Are there any softwares, tools, or helpful articles that can guide me on how to properly work from both systems?

I tried to do it by git cloning. I expect it to work on both systems without any errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This really depends on many things:

- The language/framework
- Libraries you are using
- Many more factors that are probably existent that I don't know about

For example, a project in C# *should* work on both systems, however using things like `System.Drawing` (Which is only supported on Windows) would break that compatibility. In your case, POSIX to Windows usually works fine. The only thing you can try is to just build and run it and hope for the best, and fix the errors as they come.

Comment: Why'd you delete my "Happy Coding!" @jonrsharpe D:

Comment: @jonrsharpe, currently I'll be working on mostly Javascript and Python. I just want to be sure I can work on both languages on both systems

Comment: @Jim2400 Yeah, by all means I feel JS and Python should be fine. Unless you are using python's `win32api`, which is windows-only, however JS and Python sounds like a webapp, so I wouldn't stress it. (By the way, I wrote this Answer, @jonrsharpe just edited it.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing